# SQLzoo, SELECT within SELECT tutorial

Tags: sql

I am currently doing this tutorial (http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial) and I can't answer question 8 :

**Some countries have populations more than three times that of any of their neighbours (in the same continent). Give the countries and continents.**

.. and my current query won't be accepted as the answer :

```
SELECT x.name, x.continent FROM world x
WHERE (x.population * 3) > ALL (
SELECT y.population FROM world y
WHERE x.continent = y.continent )
```

What am I doing wrong ? What is the answer ?

Comment: you are selecting countries that have at least 3 times **less** population than their neighbors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue with your query is that you're not excluding the "bigger" country itself from the result in the inner query. The correct query is:

```
SELECT x.name, x.continent
FROM world x
WHERE x.population > ALL(
    SELECT (y.population*3)
    FROM world y
    WHERE x.continent=y.continent
    AND x.name<>y.name
)
```

Note the last condition in the inner query where I'm excluding the "x" country from the list of "y" countries by doing `x.name<>y.name`. If that is not done, no rows will be returned in the result.

P.S. Usually the "exclusion" of the outer entity from the list of entities in the inner query is excluded by using `id` field, but the table on `sqlzoo` does not have `id` fields.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

```
Select name, continent
From world x
Where population > all(Select max(population)*3 From world y Where x.continent = y.continent AND y.name != x.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

This query does not use correlated subquery.
It uses subquery where the world table is joined with a subquery that generates the continent and it's corresponding second highest area multiplied by 3.
Note that the clauses have been taken care of in the join conditions.

```
select a.name, 
   a.continent
from world a
inner join ( select a.continent, max(3*a.population) as population 
         from world a
         inner join (select continent, max(3*population)as population 
                    from world group by continent)b
         on a.continent=b.continent
         and 3*a.population <> b.population 
         group by a.continent
)b
on a.continent=b.continent
and a.population> b.population
```